# Opossite action of anchorTo

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there any opposite action to the anchorTo method used in several components? I have browsed through the docs but haven't found anything useful. At some point in my app I need to removed the previously anchored component and anchor a new one. Removing the element from the DOM did not work.

```
var menu = this.getMainMenu(); //ext js panel
var tbar = this.getMainToolbar(); //ext toolbar

Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(function () {        
    //remove previously anchored ???

    //anchor the new one
    menu.anchorTo(tbar, "tl-bl?");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to call menu.removeAnchor()

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.util.Positionable-method-removeAnchor

Comment: Somehow I missed this one. Thanks